# How to use react-hook-form with my customized react-date-picker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-datepicker, react-hook-form

I am trying to use react-hook-form with my customized date-picker, but I only see this example ([Is it possible to use react-datepicker with react hooks forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60864610/is-it-possible-to-use-react-datepicker-with-react-hooks-forms)), which is using the default react-date-picker.

However, it just only works on the original react-date-picker. 
I tried the same way with my customized date-picker, and it doesn't work...

This is my customized date-picker:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import tw from "date-fns/locale/zh-TW";

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

const DatePicker = props => {
    const [date, setDate] = useState('');
    return (
        <ReactDatePicker
            className="form-control"
            selected={date}
            onChange={date => setDate(date)}
            locale={tw}
            dateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"
            dateFormatCalendar="yyyy年 MM月"
            isClearable
        />
    )
};

export default DatePicker;
```

Here is how I use react-hook-form with my customized date-picker:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import DatePicker from '../../components/UI/Form/DatePicker';

const Form = props => {
    const { register, handleSubmit, control} = useForm();

    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    }
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name='firstName' ref={register} />

            <label>Last Name:</label>
            <input type='text' name='lastName' ref={register} />

            <label>birthday:</label>
            <Controller as={DatePicker} control={control} valueName="selected" name="birthday" />

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    );
}

export default Form;
```

After I submit the form, the 'birthday' value is undefined.
Do I still need to add any props to my customized date-picker?

{
  birthday: undefined,
  firstName: "Mike",
  lastName: "Smith"
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The customised form control currently does not offer any props to control it from outside the component. For someone actually using the component, it has to have both `selected` and `onChange` fields to extract value out of it (The `react-date-picker` has these props and hence works)

`Controller` by default has an `onChange` which reads from an `event` passed to it, which is why you see it omitted from examples like this:

```
<Controller as={TextField} name="TextField" control={control} defaultValue="" />
```

To change your custom component to work with `Controlller` syntax, you can expose the `selected` and `onChange` accordingly:

```
const DatePicker = ({ selected, onChange }) => {
    return (
        <ReactDatePicker
            className="form-control"
            selected={selected}
            onChange={onChange}
            locale={tw}
            dateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"
            dateFormatCalendar="yyyy年 MM月"
            isClearable
        />
    )
};
```

and on the `Controller`:

```
<Controller 
  as={DatePicker} 
  control={control} 
  valueName="selected"
  name="birthday"
  onChange={(date) => date};
/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I know what's going on behind the scene!!

Answer (score 0):

Also it's better if you pass `onChangeName="onChangeDates"` instead so you can pass value in.

```
<ControllerWrapper
            as={
              <DatePicker
                error={has(formErrors, fieldsConfiguration.datePicker.name)}
              />
            }
            rules={fieldsConfiguration.datePicker.rules}
            name={fieldsConfiguration.datePicker.name}
            onChangeName="onChangeDates"
            onChange={dateRangePickerSelector}
          />
```